# Как проинициировать переменные класса при создании

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, инициализация

Есть класс:

```
class Node {
    public:
        lu a = 0;
        BYTE c = 0;

        Node* left;
        Node* right;

        Node() { left = right = nullptr; }

        Node(Node* l, Node* r) {
            left = l;
            right = r;
            a = (l->a) + (r->a);
        }
};
```

Сейчас есть инициализация:

```
Node* simpleNode = new Node;
simpleNode->c = item.first;
simpleNode->a = item.second;
```

А можно ли как-то сразу задать инициализацию переменных `a` и `c`?

Что-то типа:

```
auto simpleNode = new Node(a: item.second, c: item.first);
```

Comment: сделать конструктор `Node()`, который принимает `a` и `c` в качестве параметров...

Comment: @Fat-Zer а без конструктора

Comment: Если значения известны на момент компиляции - то объявляете переменные как `const` и задаёте значения. А если нет - то конструктор. (Кстати пример, который вы написали - `new Node(a: item.second, c: item.first);` это как раз пример вызова конструктора, правда с вашим собственным синтаксисом).

Comment: @Стас Спасибо, можете более подробно расписать в виде ответа?

Comment: `new Node{.a=item.second, .c=item.first}`

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, из относительно разумных решений, в c++20 можно будет убрать другие конструкторы и использовать *Designated initializers*, например... остальные решения (вроде макросов) ИМХО за гранью адекватности или будут делать сильно не то что ты хочешь...

Comment: @dIm0n а можно полный пример?

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG я не могу написать воспроизводимый пример, т.к. не знаю, что такое `item`. Надо вашу строку `auto simpleNode = new Node(a: item.second, c: item.first);` заменить на `auto simpleNode = new Node{.a=item.second, .c=item.first};`

Comment: item - это пара `std::pair<lu,BYTE>`

Comment: В msvc уже завезли эту фичу из C++20 и можно уже пользоваться.